# rubyのparallelでスレッドごとにオブジェクトを分ける方法

Tags: ruby

rubyのparallelを使って、スレッドごとにオブジェクトを分けて処理したいのですが、良い方法はありますか?

イメージ

```
Parallel.each(array, in_threads: 10) {|val|

    obj[thisThread] << val

}
```

Comment: 仮にスレッドが10個、オブジェクトが500個あったならば、1スレッドにつきオブジェクトを50個ずつ処理させたいっていうことでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.current](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/Thread/s/current.html)で現在実行中のスレッドを取得できます。
そのスレッドをキーにして`hash`に値をいれるといいのではないでしょうか。

```
require 'parallel'
require 'securerandom'
{}.tap {|hash|
  Parallel.each(10.times.to_a, in_threads: 5) {|val|
    hash[Thread.current.object_id] ||= []
    hash[Thread.current.object_id] << val

    # 全部同じスレッドで処理されるとサンプルとして分かりづらいので
    # 明示的に他のスレッドに順番を譲っています
    Thread.pass
  }
}
# => {70296018371880=>[0, 9], 70296018372240=>[1, 3, 7], 70296018372060=>[2, 5], 70296018371400=>[4, 6, 8]}
```

またスレッドごとに値を保持したいならスレッドローカル変数などを使うといいと思います。

```
require 'parallel'
require 'securerandom'
{}.tap {|hash|
  Parallel.each(10.times.to_a, in_threads: 5) {|val|
    Thread.current[:total] ||= 0
    Thread.current[:total] += val
    hash[Thread.current.object_id] = Thread.current[:total]

    # 全部同じスレッドで処理されるとサンプルとして分かりづらいので
    # 明示的に他のスレッドに順番を譲っています
    Thread.pass
  }
}
# => {70296003558440=>11, 70296003558620=>5, 70296003558880=>16, 70296003558120=>6, 70296003557940=>7}
```

ただし、`hash`にRubyに元から入っている`Hash`などのデータ構造はスレッドセーフではないので[thread_safe](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/thread_safe)などのライブラリに入っている`ThreadSafe::Hash`などをあわせて使うとよいのではないでしょうか。

```
require 'parallel'
require 'thread_safe'
require 'securerandom'
ThreadSafe::Hash.new.tap {|hash|
  Parallel.each(10.times.to_a, in_threads: 5) {|val|
    Thread.current[:total] ||= 0
    Thread.current[:total] += val
    hash[Thread.current.object_id] = Thread.current[:total]

    # 全部同じスレッドで処理されるとサンプルとして分かりづらいので
    # 明示的に他のスレッドに順番を譲っています
    Thread.pass
  }
}
# => {70280165348680=>13, 70280165348480=>6, 70280165348340=>16, 70280165348200=>10}
```

### 参考

- [Ruby core classes aren't thread-safe](http://www.jstorimer.com/pages/ruby-core-classes-arent-thread-safe)
- [Concurrency in jruby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Concurrency-in-jruby#core-classes-and-standard-library)

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'pp'
require 'parallel'

val = [].tap {|a|
  (1..100).each {|i|
    a << i
  }
}

Parallel.each(val.each_slice(10), :in_threads => 1) { |split_val|
  pp split_val
}
```

よくわからないんですがこういうことがしたいということでしょうか